# How to skip invalid characters in stream in Java/Scala?

Tags: java, scala, inputstream, streamreader

For example I have following code

```
Source.fromFile(new File( path), "UTF-8").getLines()
```

and it throws exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:260)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:319)
```

I don't care if some lines were not read, but how to skip invalid chars and continue reading lines?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can influence the way that the charset decoding handles invalid input by calling [`CharsetDecoder.onMalformedInput`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#onMalformedInput%28java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction%29).

*Usually* you won't ever see a `CharsetDecoder` object directly, because it will be created behind the scenes for you. So if you need access to it, you'll need to use API that allows you to specify the `CharsetDecoder` directly (instead of just the encoding name or the `Charset`).

The most basic example of such API is the [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder%29):

```
InputStream in = ...;
CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();
decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, decoder);
```

Note that this code uses the Java 7 class [`StandardCharsets`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html), for earlier versions you can simply replace it with [`Charset.forName("UTF-8")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) (or use [the `Charsets` class](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html) from [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)).

Comment: +1 for introducing me to StandardCharset. I've wanted that for so long. No more `catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { // never happens }`

Comment: @Thilo: if you're stuck with Java 6, then Guava provides [the `Charsets` class](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Charsets.html) which does the same thing.

Comment: Note: If you’re writing files you can get a similar error. You can set the same onMalformedInput: IGNORE on the CharsetEncoder too.

Answer (score 13):

Well, if it isn't UTF-8, it is something else. The trick is finding out what that something else is, but if all you want is avoid the errors, you can use an encoding that doesn't have invalid codes, such as `latin1`:

```
Source.fromFile(new File( path), "latin1").getLines()
```

Comment: There are unfortunately sometimes sources that provide "mostly UTF-8" and contain malformed input. And in those cases it might be acceptable to skip the broken characters and still decode the correct ones.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and one of Scala's built-in codecs did the trick for me:

```
Source.fromFile(new File(path))(Codec.ISO8859).getLines()
```

Comment: whoa, I have no idea why this worked, but you saved my evening!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid invalid characters using Scala, I found this worked for me.

```
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction
import scala.io._

object HelloWorld {

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    implicit val codec = Codec("UTF-8")

    codec.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
    codec.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)

    val dataSource = Source.fromURL("https://www.foo.com")

    for (line <- dataSource.getLines) {

      println(line)
    }
  }
}
```