# How to remove bad characters that are not suitable for utf8 encoding in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, utf-8

I have dirty data. Sometimes it contains characters like [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d86d/index.htm). I use this data to make queries like

```
WHERE a.address IN ('mydatahere')
```

For this character I get

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_bin,IMPLICIT), (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation ' IN '

How can I filter out characters like this? I use Java.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be this will help someone as it helped me.

```
public static String removeBadChars(String s) {
  if (s == null) return null;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){ 
    if (Character.isHighSurrogate(s.charAt(i))) continue;
    sb.append(s.charAt(i));
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: You want to remove those that are `isLowSurrogate()` as well. If your string has a valid >BMP character, this will leave the string corrupted I think.

Answer (score 10):

When I had problem like this, I used Perl script to ensure that data is converted to valid UTF-8 by using code like this:

```
use Encode;
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
while (<>) {
    print Encode::decode('UTF-8', $_);
}
```

This script takes (possibly corrupted) UTF-8 on `stdin` and re-prints valid UTF-8 to `stdout`. Invalid characters are replaced with `�` (`U+FFFD`, [Unicode replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replacement_character#Replacement_character)).

If you run this script on good UTF-8 input, output should be identical to input.

If you have data in database, it makes sense to use DBI to scan your table(s) and scrub all data using this approach to make sure that everything is valid UTF-8.

This is Perl one-liner version of this same script:

```
perl -MEncode -e "binmode STDOUT,':utf8';while(<>){print Encode::decode 'UTF-8',\$_}" < bad.txt > good.txt
```

---

**EDIT: Added Java-only solution**.

This is an example how to do this in Java:

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder;
import java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction;

public class UtfFix {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, CharacterCodingException {
        CharsetDecoder decoder = Charset.forName("UTF-8").newDecoder();
        decoder.onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
        decoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE);
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[] {
            (byte) 0xD0, (byte) 0x9F, // 'П'
            (byte) 0xD1, (byte) 0x80, // 'р'
            (byte) 0xD0,              // corrupted UTF-8, was 'и'
            (byte) 0xD0, (byte) 0xB2, // 'в'
            (byte) 0xD0, (byte) 0xB5, // 'е'
            (byte) 0xD1, (byte) 0x82  // 'т'
        });
        CharBuffer parsed = decoder.decode(bb);
        System.out.println(parsed);
        // this prints: Пр?вет
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i need java solution.

Comment: You'd want a CharsetEncoder with the same replacing behaviour first, to get the bytes for the input string, before then decoding it back to String.

Comment: you will need to replace ByteBuffer in this example with actual byte stream from your source - would that be text file or SQL column. gist of this example is how to make sure that your UTF-8 stream is definitely compliant UTF-8. It is up to you how do you exactly get this data into your `ByteBuffer` or `ByteArrayInputStream`

Comment: Note that if you need a Reader, rather than handling buffers directly, as of Java 7, [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder)) can accept a pre-configured `CharsetDecoder`, as in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7281034/1303595).

Comment: Why does the java solution not use ? instead of the unicode replacement character? Worse, all of the docs indicate that the default replacement character is \uFFFD... perhaps it's a bug?

Comment: I edited the post to add a backslash in the `$_` variable in the perl oneliner.

Answer (score 6):

You can encode and then decode it to/from UTF-8:

```
String label = "look into my eyes 〠.〠";

Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
label = charset.decode(charset.encode(label)).toString();

System.out.println(label);
```

output:

```
look into my eyes ?.?
```

edit: I think this might only work on Java 6.

Comment: Well, you just removed perfectly valid Unicode characters "〠.〠" using this method. Question was how to replace only _invalid_ characters, not all of them.

Comment: Just tested, it gives `look into my eyes 〠.〠` output, and that's right, because that code should not cause loss of Unicode characters, unless you are using ASCII for Java source files.

Answer (score 3):

You can filter surrogate characters with this regex:

```
String str  = ""; //U+20000, represented by 2 chars in java (UTF-16 surrogate pair)
str = str.replaceAll( "([\\ud800-\\udbff\\udc00-\\udfff])", "");
System.out.println(str.length()); //0
```

Comment: (Note this will remove all use of surrogates, not just invalid sequences.)

Comment: @bobince yeah, I am thinking of MySQL which afaik has problems with characters beyond BMP. http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25666

Comment: Ah, yes - you have to use utfmb4 to store the astral planes and that's relatively new. (Well, unless you just dump everything into a binary string or use a misleading encoding, so you don't get the benefit of Unicode-aware string collation.)

Comment: Doesn't dc00 come right after dbff? Why can't this just be "([\\ud800-\\udfff])"

Answer (score 2):

Once you convert the byte array to String on the java machine, you'll get (by default on most machines) UTF-16 encoded string. The proper solution to get rid of non UTF-8 characters is with the following code:

```
String[] values = {"\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x95", "\\xF0\\x9F\\x91\\x8C", "/*", "look into my eyes 〠.〠", "fkdjsf ksdjfslk", "\\xF0\\x80\\x80\\x80", "aa \\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x95 aa", "Ok"};
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(values[i].replaceAll(
                    //"[\\\\x00-\\\\x7F]|" + //single-byte sequences   0xxxxxxx - commented because of capitol letters
                    "[\\\\xC0-\\\\xDF][\\\\x80-\\\\xBF]|" + //double-byte sequences   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
                    "[\\\\xE0-\\\\xEF][\\\\x80-\\\\xBF]{2}|" + //triple-byte sequences   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx * 2
                    "[\\\\xF0-\\\\xF7][\\\\x80-\\\\xBF]{3}" //quadruple-byte sequence 11110xxx 10xxxxxx * 3
            , ""));
}
```

or if you want to validate if some string contains non utf8 characters you would use Pattern.matches like:

```
String[] values = {"\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x95", "\\xF0\\x9F\\x91\\x8C", "/*", "look into my eyes 〠.〠", "fkdjsf ksdjfslk", "\\xF0\\x80\\x80\\x80", "aa \\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x95 aa", "Ok"};
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Pattern.matches(
                    ".*(" +
                    //"[\\\\x00-\\\\x7F]|" + //single-byte sequences   0xxxxxxx - commented because of capitol letters
                    "[\\\\xC0-\\\\xDF][\\\\x80-\\\\xBF]|" + //double-byte sequences   110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
                    "[\\\\xE0-\\\\xEF][\\\\x80-\\\\xBF]{2}|" + //triple-byte sequences   1110xxxx 10xxxxxx * 2
                    "[\\\\xF0-\\\\xF7][\\\\x80-\\\\xBF]{3}" //quadruple-byte sequence 11110xxx 10xxxxxx * 3
                    + ").*"
            , values[i]));
}
```

For making a whole web app be UTF8 compatible read here:
[How to get UTF-8 working in Java webapps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138950/521754)
[More on Byte Encodings and Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html).
You can check your pattern [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).
The same in PHP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401317/remove-non-utf8-characters-from-string).

Comment: Can you explain the "commented out because of capital letters"?

Answer (score -1):

In PHP -  I approach this by only allowing printable data.  This really helps in cleaning the data for DB.
It's pre-processing though and sometimes you don't have that luxury.

```
$str = preg_replace('/[[:^print:]]/', '', $str);
```