# Removing invalid character from a string using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, utf-8, talend

I inserting data from mysql to postgresql using Talend and I get invalid byte sequence error. 
I used trim(both CHAR(0x00) from column_name) to remove invalid characters. 
It removed most of the errors but I am guessing there are invalid characters in the middle of string. How can I find and remove them using sql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove bad characters that are not suitable for utf8 encoding in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657019/how-to-remove-bad-characters-that-are-not-suitable-for-utf8-encoding-in-mysql)

Comment: *How* do you insert data from MySQL to PostgreSQL? With a program? In which language is the program written?

Comment: I am using Talend for ETL